# Iso osi, what is the path that the data used (hardware and software)?

Tags: ip

Sorry for my bad english.
I don't know what way the data use when it go from the layer 7 in the iso osi model to the layer 1. For example, when i write an email the message what path used? i think that the message after it is formatted, the ip (some software i think but i don't know about this) send it to the nic and this send it to ethernet cable. My questions is, what path used the data after it is send from for example an email? What physically happen to data when it is send out from the computer? Please sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The OSI model is supposed to be a guideline, not a strict set of rules for all communications. However, data usually passes through from layer 7 to 1 on the sender's side, and 1 to 7 on the receiver's side. As data goes from 7 to 1, the data is formatted (encoding/encryption) and encapsulated several times before the NIC sends it out as 0's and 1's on the media. On the opposite side, the data is decapsulated and converted back into the original format(decoding/decrypting).

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand what physically happen when data is send. For example, what happen in the computer that send data, i don't know what happen step by step, what the hardware and software do after the data is sent? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @short That question is way too broad for [su].

Comment: I did my best to summarize the process, but if you still need clarification I suggest googling each step, or asking your teacher.

Comment: Sorry. I ask because i don't know what happen when the data is sent. i think this, when we for example send an email , the massage after it is formatter it thanks to ip(software) go to nic and will be sent but when we do this the message was sent to router that with ip( hardware) sent it to nic and internet, it's true?

Comment: and... is the internet protocol hardware or software?

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande91si/www-spr04/readings/week1/InternetWhitepaper.htm

Comment: so what is the path that data used when it it send?

Comment: And the internet protocol is software or hardware?

Comment: And when the data is sent from computer, what is the router of computer that route the data to make it go to the router that is connected to modem?